# Trying to tell a visually rich story in Android by Animating views

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, renderscript

I am trying to create an animation using photos and videos to tell a story on an Android tablet above ICS. The storyboard is visually rich and animating similar to the [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=IYp8TabJ2f8).

What is the best way to do something like that. I have done some search and found that on Android we have

1. OpenGL ES 2.0, Do everything at the primitive level.
2. Renderscript, To offload computation intensive task for the native code but yet portable
3. ViewProperty Animator, Easier animation on any property on any view.

What is the best choice to go with for my case. Any help would be appreciated. For inspiration, I am looking for app links which does a similar thing. I am also looking for any library to work on top of OpenGL which can help me reach there at the earliest and for a better maintainable code.

Comment: I haven't worked with `RenderScript`, but I don't think you'll be able to pull out that kind of animations with property animators. Most likely OpenGL is the way to go. Also you're question is not a good fit for stackoverflow(asking what is the best approach without taking time to check it yourself, asking for links to apps and libraries).

Comment: @Luksprog, thank you for ur comment. I am saughting app links because I could not find anything from my search. If someone has worked on a similar thing that they can share the link to their app. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with RenderScript and it will essentially be as primitive as OpenGL and in many cases more because of the lack of libraries. OpenGL ES is in my opinion your best bet. There are many libraries available but near as I can tell you will still have quite a bit of code to write to perform the animations, load images, sync the storyline, etc. My suggestion would be to look at the [Rajawali](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/) for a very good library which contains certainly all of the features for the actual GL management. Also, as long as you aren't doing some crazy GLSL stuff, you will have a piece of software just as portable as RenderScript. The issues will come when you try and hold more textures than the GL spec, color depth, etc which RenderScript manages by essentially imposing no program being able to exceed the base Open GL spec. Also, RenderScript for graphics is deprecated which is what led our company to Rajawali. Look through his tutorials, its ability to do what you want is certainly there, if you are willing to write the glue code.